# Pulling JSON data from Hearthstone API

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to create a random Hearthstone card generator and I am having trouble with pulling the JSON data from the API and converting it into a JS object so I can input the text into my HTML. I have tested the request on request maker so the API request works fine, however theres obviously some other problem that I'm missing. I've tried the various syntax for converting the JSON data into a JS object, but it's just not working. Im thinking that maybe there's something wrong with the callback function I put into the success key/value pair. Nevertheless I've looked quite a bit for a solution and I have changed up a few things but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated!

So what I would like to happen is when that next button is clicked, it will retrieve the data and input it into the specified elements on the screen. The data I am trying to grab is all cards with the only parameter Im using is the collectable one, so I'd like to pull a random card each time the arrow is clicked.

Also,here is a link to the API itself: https://market.mashape.com/omgvamp/hearthstone.

```
var cardImage = '', cardName = '', cardType = '', cardFaction = '',
 cardRarity = '', playerClass = '', artistName = '';
function cardInfo() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards? collectible=1",
        headers: {
            "x-mashape-key": "mXtnPm3ltOmshc9dQJjtVdKzfnhbp14UZncjsnfzwvp6uLiMwH",
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            cardImage = obj.image;
            cardName = obj.name;
            cardType = obj.type;
            cardFaction = obj.faction;
            cardRarity = obj.rarity;
            playerClass = obj.playerClass;
            artistName = obj.artist;

            $("#card-image").attr(src, obj.image);
            $("#card-name").html(obj.name);
            $("#card-type").text(obj.type);
            $("#card-faction").text(obj.faction);
            $("#card-rarity").text(obj.rarity);
            $("#player-class").text(obj.playerClass);
            $("#artist-name").text(obj.artist);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    })
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nextCard').click(cardInfo())
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nextCard').click(cardInfo())
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty much there - just needed to tweak the request a little - the docs specify a GET request for that particular endpoint. Your request was responding with `{"error":400,"message":"Token mismatch exception."}` with a 400 HTTP status code.

Also cards are returned in their sets (classic/naxx/etc.) so I've flattened the object a little to make selecting a random card easier. I also tweaked the request to better reflect the mashape docs http://docs.mashape.com/javascript.

You also missed the quotes around 'src' when trying to set the images `src` attribute and `obj.image` is undefined and should have been `obj.img`

Finally I removed a few superfluous variables.

Click the next button to perform a request (One isn't triggered initially) also it was a little slow to respond for me so give it a few secs.

```js
var cards;
var dataPromise;

function getCardData() {
  if(!dataPromise){
    dataPromise = $.ajax({ // Store jQuery promise so that we can return it for subsequent calls ensuring only one AJAX request is made
      url: 'https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards?collectible=1',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "mXtnPm3ltOmshc9dQJjtVdKzfnhbp14UZncjsnfzwvp6uLiMwH");
      }
    });
  } 
  return dataPromise;
}

function showCardRandom(){
  var cardNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length); // Select a random card number
  showCard(cardNo)
}

function showCard(cardNo){
  var obj = cards[cardNo];
  $("#card-image").attr('src', obj.img);
  $("#card-name").html(obj.name);
  $("#card-type").text(obj.type);
  $("#card-faction").text(obj.faction);
  $("#card-rarity").text(obj.rarity);
  $("#player-class").text(obj.playerClass);
  $("#artist-name").text(obj.artist);
}

function flattenCards(data){
    // Flatten the object as cards are stored in sets
    var result = [];
    for (var set in data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data[set].length; i++) {
        result.push(data[set][i]);
      }
    }
    return result;
}

getCardData(); // Start loading card data ASAP - subsequent calls will return the same promise anyway

$(document).ready(function() {
  getCardData()
    .done(function(data){
       $("#nextCard").text("Next");
       cards = flattenCards(data);
       showCardRandom();
    });
  $('#nextCard').click(showCardRandom);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="card-image">
<div id="card-name"></div>
<div id="card-type"></div>
<div id="card-faction"></div>
<div id="card-rarity"></div>
<div id="player-class"></div>
<div id="artist-name"></div>
<button id="nextCard">Loading Data...</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize that the type was post, I was working on this really late trying to tweak some things to make it work and I guess I ended up making some lack-of-sleep errors haha. Any idea why it takes a few seconds for it to load? Is it just that the request is that fast or is there any way to make the request faster? Again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: All good we've all been there :) There's 2 reasons why it's slow I think - it takes ~2s for by browser to start receiving a response then another ~2s to receive the data as it's 639KB worth. The simplest optimization would be to not re-request the data and just select another card from the existing data. The second would be to cache the data on your server and use a server side script to return a few cards at a time that way you'd load only a small amount of data and could pre-load a few cards to keep the UI responsive :) I'll update my example so that it only performns one AJAX request

Comment: I've updated my answer - getCardData now returns a promise which makes it easy to only perform a single request (adding error handling would also be advisable), the API request is made loading before DOM ready and only one AJAX request is ever made making everything a whole lot more responsive. The next step for something like this would be to refactor it into an Object to keep things neat and tidy and pre-caching the next image or 2. If you feel my answer has resolved your issue if you could please mark it as the accepted answer that would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If the response is of type json then try doing it this way.

```
 var cardImage = JObject.Parse(response.Result).GetValue("image");
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately no dice. I do really appreciate you taking out your time to help me though!

Comment: Can you send me what value you are getting in "response" based on which I can help you..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wget. This W10 batch can helps you:

```
wget --no-check-certificat --header "X-Mashape-Key: Xif91aru03mshCEYjRubsWyyaI8gp1AV79RjsntjSNoNcgcyZj" "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards" --output-document=cards%datetime%.js
```

BTW: mashape looks like closed, use https://rapidapi.com/omgvamp/api/hearthstone instead of it. With this script, you can save the full cardlist to cards[date].js file. You have to write into the script your own key!

```
var unirest   = require("unirest");
var fs        = require('fs');
var strftime  = require('strftime');

const fil="cards" + strftime('%y.%m.%d');

var req = unirest("GET", "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.rapidapi.com/cards");

req.query({
    "region": "us",
    "locale": "enUS"
});

req.headers({
    "x-rapidapi-host": "omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "your registered keystring",
    "useQueryString": true
});


req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
    else {
        //console.log(res.body);
        fs.writeFileSync(
        './' + fil + '.js', 
        JSON.stringify( res.body, 0, 1), 
     function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(file, err);
        }           
    });
    }
});
```